# Handle collection of generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I need to model in C# a context related to a Taekwondo competition where there is a tournament composed of more matches. Specifically, in relation to the initial number of athletes, a tournament can have at most 3 matches: Eliminatory, Semifinal and Final. In each match, I want to keep track of the Poomsaes (a kind of athlete exhibition) made by the athletes. In an eliminatory or a semifinal match, there is a particular kind of Poomsae with a certain expected result, different in type from the one in a final case (different parameters etc.).

So I have an interface that represents a generic match (which contains Poomsaes capable of handling a specific type of PoomsaeResult). Because of the difficulties of having properties with generic types I divided the concept into two methods.

```
public interface IMatch<R, P> where R : IPoomsaeResult where P : IPoomsae<R>
{
    void AddScheduledPoomsae(P poomsae);

    ISet<P> GetScheduledPoomsaes();
}
```

And two implementations, whose interfaces simply are:

```
public interface IStandardMatch : IMatch<IStandardPoomsaeResult, IStandardPoomsae>
{
}

public interface IFinalMatch : IMatch<IFinalPoomsaeResult, IFinalPoomsae>
{
}
```

In the Tournament class I would like to have so a dictionary that associates each stage of the tournament (enumeration for Eliminatory, Semifinal and Final) to the related match, in order to achieve something like this:

```
Dictionary<TournamentStage, IMatch> matches = new Dictionary<TournamentStage, IMatch>();

matches.Add(TournamentStage.Semifinal, new StandardMatch());
matches.Add(TournamentStage.Final, new FinalMatch());
```

The problem is that IMatch is generic and I must specify a type even if I would like to support any type of match. Can someone with experience in C # suggest solutions to the problem or better ways to model it?

---

IMatch has two generics because I have modelled IPoomsae with this approach:

```
public interface IPoomsae<R> where R : IPoomsaeResult
{
    int MemberId { get; }

    R Result { get; }
}

public interface IStandardPoomsae : IPoomsae<IStandardPoomsaeResult>
{
    // Extra
}

public interface IFinalPoomsae : IPoomsae<IFinalPoomsaeResult>
{
    // Extra
}
```

In fact, each Poomsae has an id related to the athlete who has done it and a kind of result (which is different for standard and final cases).

Comment: This seems like a broken design. What puspose does a generic interface have, when you store instances of it in a non-generic way? Having said this even if you *could* do this, what type of instance do you expect to get when using `matches[Tournament.SemiFinal]`? It surely can only return some **un**-generic match, making all you generic appraoches on `Match` quite useless. You can´t expect the compiler to guess the exact type of the object to return.

Comment: Even if dictionary were to allow this, you are not going to be able to use the eventual elements because they types and signatures will differ. I would recommend not overengineering. Start with one static function main and write only enough code to allow your tests to pass. In particular, I don't any need for a TournamentStage class. A good analogy is in the bowling game kata often shown; it could have been engineered up-front with classes for everything, or it could be just as simple as possible. See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFGFk0Fnztg

Comment: This is not heading the right way.  The *kind* of match is a property, not a type.

Comment: There is a C# tutorial about tournament traker from TimCorey. Im not saying that you need a tutorial but as tournament traker is a classic 1rst application. Some of the tutorial will give you a glance on how other could have tackle the problem. If you need the code there is a ton of copy on github )

Comment: Thanks to all. I wanted to try to adopt a general solution and avoid a rigid structure like that represented by distinct properties for each tournament stage, but this led me to a wrong design (as evidenced by @HimBromBeere). I will move towards a solution with the kind of match expressed as property, using a TDD approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to shoehorn different types of match into one (generic) type. Instead, perhaps:

```
public class Tournament {
    public Round Eliminatory;
    public Round Semifinal;
    public FinalRound Final;
}
```

I don't think you need the dictionary either, although you could consider changing the Eliminator and Semifinal above into a list or array of "pre-final" rounds. In any case, the above keeps the types separate so that the results can be separate as well.